# How to handle double escaping in chrome/firefox?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, taglib

Here is my my java code in jsp :

```
custUrl="customer.action?custId=211&custAddressId=2341";
```

Now javascript code :

```
function submit() {
    window.location = "<c:out value='<%=custUrl%>' />";
    //  here is generated javascript code
    //  window.location = "customer.action?custId=211&amp;custAddressId=2341"
}
```

FireFox and Chrome (IE does not do double escape) are escaping the already escaped value (that's why I am getting the second paramter name as `amp;custAddressId` instead of `custAddressId`).

Is there any generic solution where i can handle double escaping in firefox/chrome?

**UPDATE:-**
so bottom line is i want to escape the intended characters  with c:out (which is happening)
but also want to avoid the double escaping while sending the data to server which is happening
in case of some browsers

Comment: Could you please elaborate on intended characters and what you mean when you say "which is happening"?

Answer (score 0):

By default special characters are escaped by `<c:out>`. Turn escaping off as

```
<c:out value='<%=custUrl%>' escapeXml='false' />
```

Ampersand `&` is escaped as `&amp;` in XML. Here `amp` is short for ampersand.

This isn't a Firefox/Chrome issue because final HTML generated is the same irrespective of which browser you use to access your site. IE's HTML source viewer must have chosen to display the ampersand in its unescaped form.

Comment: Correct but how could `"customer.action?custId=211&custAddressId=2341";` turn to `"customer.action?custId=211&amp;custAddressId=2341"` , `&` converted to `&amp;` !!

Comment: Ampersand `&` is escaped as `&amp;` in XML. amp there stands for ampersand.

Comment: @Ravi with escapeXml i am skipping the escaping altogether which i dont want. See update in my post